# Url repeating each time causing no template found error

Tags: python

[everything works fine on first click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyqcH.png)
[url is repeated again causing no template error**strong text**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZxRr.png)

on second click only id should be passed like first screenshot instead of repeating the route again

```html
 <div class="dropdown">
                        <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"  role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                    category
                        </a>
            
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            {% for j in catism %}
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="viewalls/{{j.id}}">{{j.cat_name}}</a></li>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

urls.py

from django.urls import path,include
from .import views

urlpatterns=[
path('',views.home,name='home'),

```
path('viewalls/<int:id>',views.view_all,name='views'),
path('viewall',views.view_all,name='view_all'),


path('addproduct',views.add_product,name='add_product'),
path('remove_product',views.remove_product,name='remove_product'),
path('remove/<int:id>',views.remove_product,name='remove_product'),
# path('filter_product',views.filter_product)

# path('login/',include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))
```

]

views.py

`def view_all(request,id=0):
pros=product.objects.all()
cats=category.objects.all()
if id:
cat=category.objects.get(id=id)
pros=pros.filter(cat_id__cat_name=cat)
return render(request,'prohome.html',{'context':pros,'catism':cats})

```
return render(request,'prohome.html',{'context':pros,'catism':cats})`
```

Comment: Your question seems to be related to [tag:django], please tag it as such. There are several formatting issues with your question as well. You can [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of the code:

```js
href="viewalls/{{j.id}}"
```

Should be changed in:

```js
href="/viewalls/{{j.id}}"
```

Because **with** a `/`, you are redirecting relative to the root.

But **without** a `/`, you are redirecting relative to the current endpoint.